# Place images symetric both in hor & vertical

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have several of images with equal in their dimensions which I read their file paths from an xml.
And I would like to place these images on iPhone screen programmatically. Up to here everything is fine. I'm using cocos2d solely.

Do you know any API that would help me ?
I'll supply these information
- distance both in vertical and horizontal to the neighboring images
- available drawable area
- where does the drawable area start and end

I can of course do it by code but this seemed to me very common problem for most of developers and though may be someone already implemented

thx

Comment: Are you trying to get random images of the same dimension into the same place, without having to program them each time?